# Coq XML Protocol: a likely PrintAST malfunction

Tags: xml, coq, coq-tactic, coqide, coq-extraction

I am using the XML Protocol from Coq 8.6.1. When I tried the PrintAst call, I failed to get an AST, but got an "todo" instead. Is this a malfunction or did I do something wrong? How should I get an AST from a print AST call?

Here is my case:
I used `coqtop -toploop coqidetop -main-channel stdfds` to open an ideslave process, an then input the Coq code from `coq-8.6.1/theories/FSets/FSetCompat.v`.

Here I use "<<<<<<<" to enclose some detailed procedures if you would like to repeat my experiment.

<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

First, I input

```
<call val="Add"><pair><pair><string>(***********************************************************************)
(*  v      *   The Coq Proof Assistant  /  The Coq Development Team    *)
(* &lt;O___,, *        INRIA-Rocquencourt  &amp;  LRI-CNRS-Orsay              *)
(*   \VV/  *************************************************************)
(*    //   *      This file is distributed under the terms of the      *)
(*         *       GNU Lesser General Public License Version 2.1       *)
(***********************************************************************)

(** * Compatibility functors between FSetInterface and MSetInterface. *)

Require Import FSetInterface FSetFacts MSetInterface MSetFacts.
</string><int>1</int></pair><pair><state_id val="1"/><bool val="true"/></pair></pair></call>
```

then

```
<call val="Add"><pair><pair><string>Set Implicit Arguments.
</string><int>1</int></pair><pair><state_id val="2"/><bool val="true"/></pair></pair></call>
```

then

```
<call val="Add"><pair><pair><string>Unset Strict Implicit.
</string><int>1</int></pair><pair><state_id val="3"/><bool val="true"/></pair></pair></call>
```

and finally

```
<call val="Add"><pair><pair><string>
(** * From new Weak Sets to old ones *)

Module Backport_WSets
 (E:DecidableType.DecidableType)
 (M:MSetInterface.WSets with Definition E.t := E.t
                        with Definition E.eq := E.eq)
 &lt;: FSetInterface.WSfun E.
</string><int>1</int></pair><pair><state_id val="4"/><bool val="true"/></pair></pair></call>
```

<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

At this time, I called `<call val="PrintAst"><state_id val="5"/></call>`, which I expect to return the AST of

```
Module Backport_WSets
 (E:DecidableType.DecidableType)
 (M:MSetInterface.WSets with Definition E.t := E.t
                        with Definition E.eq := E.eq)
 &lt;: FSetInterface.WSfun E.
```

To my disappointment, I got

```
<value val="good"><gallina begin="42" end="228"><todo begin="42" end="228">Module&nbsp;Backport_WSets&nbsp;(E:&nbsp;DecidableType.DecidableType)
&nbsp;&nbsp;(M:&nbsp;MSetInterface.WSets&nbsp;with&nbsp;Definition&nbsp;E.t&nbsp;:=&nbsp;E.t&nbsp;with&nbsp;Definition
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;E.eq&nbsp;:=&nbsp;E.eq)&lt;:&nbsp;FSetInterface.WSfun&nbsp;E.</todo></gallina></value>
```

By pretty printing it is

```
<value val="good">
    <gallina begin="42" end="228">
        <todo begin="42" end="228">Module Backport_WSets (E: DecidableType.DecidableType)
  (M: MSetInterface.WSets with Definition E.t := E.t with Definition
   E.eq := E.eq)<: FSetInterface.WSfun E.</todo>
    </gallina>
</value>
```

But this is merely a copy of the code! It even didn't apply a lexer... Why would this happen? Could somebody help? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `print_ast` call was never completed and it has been removed in newer Coq versions.

If you need a structured representation of Coq data I recommend Coq SerAPI which is based on automatic serialization. [Disclaimer: I am the author]

Edit: how to do that in SerAPI:

```
echo '
(Add () "From Coq Require Import FSetInterface FSetFacts MSetInterface MSetFacts.

(** * From new Weak Sets to old ones *)

Module Backport_WSets
 (E:DecidableType.DecidableType)
 (M:MSetInterface.WSets with Definition E.t := E.t
                        with Definition E.eq := E.eq)
 <: FSetInterface.WSfun E.")
(Query () (Ast 3))
' | ./sertop.native --printer=human
```

yields [after removing location info from the AST which is quite verbose]:

```
((CoqAst
  (VernacDefineModule ()
    (Id Backport_WSets)
    (((Id E)))
      (CMident
       (Ser_Qualid (DirPath ((Id DecidableType))) (Id DecidableType))
       DefaultInline)
     (()
      (((Id M)))
      ((CMwith
        (CMwith
         (CMident
          (Ser_Qualid (DirPath ((Id MSetInterface))) (Id WSets))))
        (CWith_Definition
         (((Id E) (Id t)))
         (CRef
          (Qualid
           ((Ser_Qualid (DirPath ((Id E))) (Id t))))
          ()))
        (CWith_Definition
         (((Id E) (Id eq)))
         (CRef
          (Qualid
           ((Ser_Qualid (DirPath ((Id E))) (Id eq))))
          ()))
        DefaultInline)))
     (Check
      (CMapply
       (CMident
        (Ser_Qualid (DirPath ((Id FSetInterface))) (Id WSfun))))
      ((v (CMident (Ser_Qualid (DirPath ()) (Id E))))
       DefaultInline)))
    ()))
```

what is more, Coq and SerAPI provide these days a generic mapping system form ASTs to input buffer location.

Comment: On a more general note, it seems that Coq users are pretty good at going _against_ the recommendations from upstream; that includes developing plugins for old versions, insisting in using deprecated features, etc... Hint: your life won't be easy and frustration will be high. We all know the Coq compatibility story has been far from pleasant in the last years, but upstream has strong reasons to recommend what they think is the path of least pain, and it is indeed making a large effort trying to make interacting with Coq a smoother experience, but Rome wasn't built on a single day.

Comment: Thanks! The main reason why I am using an older version is that I am having a look at Compcert, and it hasn't supported Coq 8.7 yet. I assume that this is the case for most Coq projects. I am afraid there will be some bugs if I run these projects on Coq 8.7.

Comment: Compcert does support 8.7 and 8.8. Most important projects do too. Cheers.

Comment: By the way, for this kind of questions you may have better luck asking at Coq's gitter channel https://gitter.im/coq/coq

Comment: I see. Sounds great! I will try the newest version with SerAPI!

Comment: Cool. Let's chat on gitter thou, I'd be great having a more concrete idea on what you would like do, in Coq upstream we are very interested in trying to provide a smooth experience to users/tool writers.